# A variable set in zshrc will not disappear when opening another terminal

Tags: macos, zsh, zshrc

My OS is Mac OSX

First, I use `oh-my-zsh` as configuration.

In `.zshrc` I add

```
(( ZSH_COUNT = ZSH_COUNT + 1 ))
export ZSH_COUNT
if [[ ${ZSH_COUNT} -lt 2 ]]; then
    gspull_main
fi
```

The purpose is when I first open the terminal after booting the computer, it will run `gspull_main`(zshell function in .zshrc). But then it will never run until my next time booting.

I set a variable `ZSH_COUNT` to log this action.  But when I open another terminal, it seemed unset the variable (run the program again).

**Update:2016-04-30**

I put the code into another file called `.zsh_yy` and then made a `startupscript.bash`

```
#!/bin/bash
#Wait for however long you want:
sleep 10
open -a iterm
sleep 60
rm ~/.log_yy
zsh ~/.bin/.zsh_yy > ~/.log_yy  #<--problem, how to transfer this command into iterm?
# /path/to/exec/theExec
```

Comment: Why don't put your program in `rc.local`?

Comment: @cuonglm the program is zsh function.

Comment: You can convert it to `sh`, or simply call `zsh gspull_main` in `/etc/rc.local`.

Comment: @cuonglm I am not familiar with `/etc/rc.local`. But does it run before system reads .zshrc or after system reads .zshrc. (Because I want to  see the information created by the zsh program. Also I need to input password.)

Comment: you'll need to source the variable in the second shell.  Frankly, I'd avoid the export by writing the value of ZSH_COUNT to a file.

Comment: @yuxuan: `/etc/rc.local` run after other run levels, before reading `.zshrc`. Sound like you should create a lock file after run script, and check if the file is existed, then skip.

Comment: @cuonglm I think `zsh ~/.bin/.zsh_yy` is good, so I extract the code from `.zshrc` and put it into `~/.bin/.zsh_yy` and make a `startupscript.bash`. But problem is I can't see the information created by the  command `zsh ~/.bin/.zsh_yy` so I add `>~/.log_gspull`